# Translating prometheus LOG4j conf from XML to properties file

Tags: log4j2, properties-file, prometheus

I have used LOG4j many times on quite common basics, and mainly through a properties file. I am though very unfamiliar with the XML form and with uncommon features (such as third party lib custom logging).

The [prometheus log4j2 configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#logging) is written for xml conf files, and I actually don't understand it. Although I could use it as such, I would like to understand it by translating in a form I am confortable with : as a properties file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="io.prometheus.client.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Prometheus name="METRICS"/>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="METRICS"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

properties file :

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = /var/logs
appenders = console, METRICS?

appenders.METRICS?.
...?

rootLogger.appenderRefs = METRICS, console
...?
```

Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=CONSOLE,METRICS

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}][%c] \:%m%n

log4j.appender.METRICS=io.prometheus.client.log4j.InstrumentedAppender
```

after see log4j_appender_total flag in prometheus

converstion refer: https://www.journaldev.com/10698/log4j-properties-file-example